# Flutter process Debug Resources not working Failed error

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I tried firebase Authorize example with e-mail and password when I trying connection firebase i gettin some error

**My build.grandle is:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':app')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Error Messages:**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:processDebugResources
\--- :app:processDebugResources (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

Comment: what is your google-services version in gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide the version of google-services in your application. Add this line inside dependencies in your build.gradle file.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Like this.

```
dependencies {
  // Add this line
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
}
```